# Plot only unique rows from large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe of 434300 rows with the following structure:

```
       x    y        p1  p2 
1      8.0  1.23e-6  10  12
2      7.9  4.93e-6  10  12
3      7.8  7.10e-6  10  12
...
.
...
4576   8.0  8.85e-6  5   16
4577   7.9  2.95e-6  5   16
4778   7.8  3.66e-6  5   16
...
...
...
434300 ...
```

with the key point being that for every block of varying x,y data there are p1 and p2 that *do not vary*. Note that these blocks of constant p1,p2 are of varying length so it is not simply a matter of slicing the data every *n* rows.

I would like to plot the values p1 vs p2 in a graph, but would only like to plot the unique points.

If i do plot p1 vs p2 using:

```
In [1]: fig=plt.figure()
In [2]: ax=plt.subplot(111)
In [3]: ax.plot(df['p1'],df['p2'])
In [4]: len(ax.lines[0].get_xdata())
Out[4]: 434300
```

I see that matplotlib is plotting each individual line of data which is to be expected.

What is the neatest way to plot only the unique points from columns p1 and p2?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/leobrowning92/861d92332bea14266b26e44029cb323b) is a csv of a small example dataset that has all of the important features of my dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop the duplicates and plot:

```
df.drop_duplicates(how='all', columns=['p1', 'p2'])[['p1', 'p2]].plot()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slice the `p1` and `p2` columns from the data frame and then drop duplicates before plotting.

```
sub_df = df[['p1','p2']].drop_duplicates()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(sub_df['p1'],sub_df['p2'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('exampleData.csv')

d = data[['p1', 'p2']].drop_duplicates()

plt.plot(d['p1'], d['p2'], 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555994/extract-unique-combinations-of-subset-of-parameters-from-tidy-data) answer to a similar question in R (which is what the pandas dataframes are based on) I found the pandas function `pandas.Dataframe.drop_duplicates`. If we modify my example code as follows:

```
In [1]: fig=plt.figure()
In [2]: ax=plt.subplot(111)
In [3]: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['p1','p2'],inplace=True)
In [3]: ax.plot(df['p1'],df['p2'])
In [4]: len(ax.lines[0].get_xdata())
Out[4]: 15
```

We see that this restricts df to only the unique points to be plotted. An important point is that you must pass a subset to `drop_duplicates` so that it only uses those columns to determine duplicate rows.